# Transfer Size limit for SCP, SFTP, RSYNC?

Tags: rsync, ftp, scp, tcp, large-files

Is there a maximum size limit to the size of collective size of the files that are to be transferred in one go for the above protocol. My intent is to know if for example after 1 GB any of these transfer protocols would start dropping packets? What would be the best protocol/technique/method to use for transferring large file sizes?

I read of the above issues where file transfers for BIG files don't match the size at the source and target. I know SCP and FTP work on TCP and should not have packet drops!

Answer (score 2):

There might be a limit on 32 bit versions of these applications, especially older versions not compiled with "large file support". Those problems were **not** a result of packets being dropped, but on writing (and/or reading) the files at the appropriate size. Back in 1995 there were similar problems with `tar` under Irix not support files > 2Gb.

So make sure you have 64-bit versions of the application you are using on both the sending and on the receiving side.

`rsync --version` will show you (among other things) `64-bit files`.

`scp` doesn't have such output AFAIK, but if you check `type scp` and then use `file /usr/bin/scp` (specifying the path that you get from `type`), and get `64-bit LSB ..x86-64` you are ok. Similar for `sftp`

Comment: You don't need “64-bit versions” (which means amd64 (or armv8, alpha, sparc64, …)), you need versions with 64-bit file size support, which should include anything compiled in the 21st century, even if they're 32-bit (x86_32, …) binaries.